# Make elements draggable within an iframe

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have an iframe within one of my webpages.  It points to another page on the same domain.  I've been trying to make the elements draggable within it and I'm having trouble.  I got it working last night but make some changes before saving that version and now can't figure out how I had it before so I know it can be done.  I have the iframe highlighting elements right now but when I put the code to drag and drop in as I had it before, it doesn't work.  The code in the main page is:

```
function init() {
var $head = $("#myframe").contents().find("head");
$head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: "http://ajax.googleapis.com     /ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/themes/base/jquery-ui.css", type: "text/css" }));
        $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "javascript", href: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5/jquery.min.js", type: "text/javascript" }));
        $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "javascript", href: "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8/jquery-ui.min.js", type: "text/javascript" }));
        $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "stylesheet", href: "my_styles.css", type: "text/css" }));
    }
    function iframeLoad() {
        $head.append($("<link/>", { rel: "javascript", href: "my_js.js", type: "text/javascript" }));
    }
```

My code for the jquery to drag and drop is:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
   $("p").draggable();
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("h1").draggable();
  });
  $(document).ready(function() {
 $("div").draggable();
 });
```

The url is:  http://johnverber.com/Opti/url.html in case you want to see it.

Comment: Is this code inside or outside of the iframe?

Comment: it's on the outside of the frame.  The draggable code is in a separate .js file and the append() is in the url.html page where the iframe is located.  I'm appending into the iframe.

Answer (score 0):

Not a full answer to your question but can't do code examples in comments clearly. You can clean up that last bit, you don't need to check if the DOM has loaded 3 times. Combine it into one:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("p,h1,div").draggable();
});
```

Comment: I believe I can put
     $("p").draggable();
     .....
etc in one function but when I try it as you showed it says that I'm missing the end paren'

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are creating 'link' tags for your js files when it should be 'script' tags.

Comment: Yeah I tried them with script tags as well didn't work at all.